# Name of poem: dangers of nuclear war/energy, referencing music of philharmonic orchestra/trio/cricket

Tags: identification-request, poetry

In the late 1970’s or early 1980’s, I read a poem warning of the dangers nuclear war or perhaps the dangers of nuclear energy.  I’m trying to find/remember that poem.

It had lines something like …

> All is alright
> All is in order
> The philharmonic orchestra continued
> to make the music that …

And later

> All is alright
> All is in order
> the philharmonic trio continued
> to make the music that …

And later

> All is alright
> All is in order
> The philharmonic cricket continued
> to make the music, that (…)
> until it too was silenced.

Unfortunately, my google-fu is failing me.  Hoping someone here knows it, or knows of a good literature specific search tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be **"Apocalypse" by DJ Enright**. [Found here](https://www.menwhosaidno.org/poetry/PoetryNuclear_apocalypse.html):

> 'After the New Apocalypse, very few members were still in possession of their instruments. Hardly a musician could call a decent suit his own. Yet, by the early summer of 1945, strains of sweet music floated on the air again. While the town still reeked of smoke, charred buildings and the stench of corpses, the Philharmonic Orchestra bestowed the everlasting and imperishable joy which music never fails to give.'
>
> [...]
>
> After the Newer Apocalypse, very few members
> Were still in possession of their instruments
> (Very few were still in possession of their members),
> And their suits were chiefly indecent.
> Yet, while the town still reeked of smoke, etc,
> The Philharmonic Trio bestowed, etc.
>
> [...]
>
> But the flute was left. And one is enough.
> All, in a sense, goes on. All is in order.
>
> [...]
>
> One day, a reed-warbler stepped on him by accident.
> However, all, in a sense, goes on. Still the everlasting and imperishable joy
> Which music never fails to give is being given.

I found this by searching the web for `poem nuclear "philharmonic orchestra"` (figuring that the exact phrase "philharmonic orchestra" was unlikely to be misremembered, even if "philharmonic trio" might be).

Comment: Wow.  That is so different than my memory of it, yet checks so many of the fragments of my memory, that it must be right.